# Where to store app location data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have an app that needs to retrieve the longitude/latitude coordinates of the device when it's opened, and then communicate with the server using these coordinates. My app is based on a `UITabBarController` so has different pages, some of which need to use this location data. I also need to implement pull to refresh on some of these pages.

What I need to know is: Where should I store the location coordinates and where should I implement the `CLLocationManager`? Should I have a location manager inside each class that needs location, or should it be in the app delegate?

Thanks

Comment: You can subclass `UITabbarViewController` class, and get user location from that.

Comment: you may create a kinda singleton on _controller-layer_ which updates the location's value for itself, and read the current value anytime from that class when you need it during runtime. piece of cake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a singleton location manager class (say, `MyLocationManager`). Your `.h` file can look like this:

```
@interface MyLocationManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentLocation;

+ (id)sharedInstance;

- (void)updateCurrentLocation;

@end
```

Then in the `.m` file implement the methods:

```
#import "MyLocationManager.h"

@interface MyLocationManager ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation MyLocationManager

#pragma mark - Singleton methods

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t token;
    static id shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&token, ^{
        shared = [[super alloc] initUniqueInstance];
    });

    return shared;
}

- (id)initUniqueInstance {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Public methods

- (void)updateCurrentLocation {
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

@end
```

Implement the delegate methods and update the `currentLocation` property when you get the updated value. I'd also advice to check for geolocation permissions somewhere and react appropriately. And keep in mind that you should use notifications (NSNotificationCenter) to inform other objects about updates to singleton's properties, not delegation (generally, you shouldn't tie your singleton to any object). Good luck!